# AWS ECS - Deploying two different microservices in a single ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have two microservices that need to be deployed in the same ECS service for efficient resource usage.

Both of them have the same context path so cannot use path-pattern filter in the ALB and ECS doesn't seem to allow multiple ALB's in a single ECS.

Is it possible to have two target groups serving the micro services at different ports ? Or is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can have two different Target groups each with a unique Port under the same ALB. I use this construction to support HTTP and HTTPS protocol on the same instance with ALB. Should be the same for ECS

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely have a single ALB serving up two different microservices on different ports of ECS instances. Typically when you're going this far, you might want to look at dynamic port mapping. The ALB still needs a way to decide which target group to go to -- hostname matching, for instance.

What I'm not totally sure I understand is why you want to share an ECS service -- why not put each microservice in its own ECS service and share an ALB instead?

Anyway, both are likely possible.  I have several microservices, each with their own ECS service sharing ECS instances and an ALB in a cluster using host name matching on the ALB. If you really want to use a single ECS service, it seems like it would still be possible.

Comment: I have now decided to go with multiple ECS services each with their own load balancers as host and path patterns did not satisfy my use-case.